# android launch gmail application from my application with a search term

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, gmail-imap

I am developing an android application in which I have to open gmail application on a button click with some search criteria , example like If the user enters a mail id or subject and search then gmail app should be launched which shows mails from that particular user id/subject . Please let me know if this is feasible.